# ImportError: No module named 'mysite' from omv of pi3

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache

I want to work with `Apache 2` and `Django 2.0.`
So I modified /etc/apache2/sites-sites-available/000-default.conf and /home/duen/django/mysite/wsgi.py.

```
python = 3.4.2
django = 2.0
apache = 2.4.10
device = raspbarry pi 3 model B
os = OpenMediaVault 3.0.88
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
  ServerAdmin sin12070@gmail.com
  DocumentRoot / var / www / html
  ErrorLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /error.log
  CustomLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /access.log combined
  WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path = / home / duen / django / mysite: /home/duen/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
  WSGIScriptAlias ​​/ /home/duen/django/mysite/wsgi.py
  <Directory / home / duen / django / mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append ('/ hoem / duen / django')
sys.path.append ('/ hoem / duen / django / mysite')
sys.path.append ('/ home / duen / django / venv / lib / python3.4 / site-packages')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault ("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application ()
```

However, when I accessed the web page, I could see this error in error.log.

**error.log**

```
mod_wsgi (pid=9040): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/duen/django/mysite/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/home/duen/django/mysite/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't telling mod_wsgi to run your WSGI application in the daemon process group you setup. Change:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/home/duen/django/mysite:/home/duen/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias ​​/ /home/duen/django/mysite/wsgi.py
```

to:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/home/duen/django/mysite \
    python-home=/home/duen/django/venv
WSGIScriptAlias ​​/ /home/duen/django/mysite/wsgi.py \
    process-group=mysite application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Also note I changed to using `python-home`, which is the recommended way of specifying the virtual environment location.

For details on how to set up the virtual environment properly see:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: FIRST, Thank you for your comment but I can't solve this problem because I have got same log.. help me.